# Moment JS- React 18

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, momentjs

i want to ask about the moment of a date which is recuperated from MongoDB (creation Date)
The problem is when i work with the moment to the (creation date)which is recuperated from MongoDB, i got the current date (date of today)!!
There are two screenshots that can explain more:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1EPH.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnUod.png)

i worked with moment js and i want other propositions if found
Thank you so much

Comment: Please add your code in the form of a code snippet instead of images. Images don't allow the people trying to help to copy/past

Comment: First, add your code snippet, it's more easiest for us debug and try the code instead of images.
Second, I think that `clientNonValidatedList.status.date_creattion` is `undefined`, check this because in this case is the same thing to write `moment()`, alias get the now date.